# how to search files and display progress bar in powershell

Tags: windows, file, powershell, get-childitem

I am currently coding in Powershell, and I am now looking for a way to display the progress bar while searching the system for documents. I am using `Get-ChildItem` instead of a loop, since it is *much* faster and more efficient than a loop. I have already figured out how to use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet, but I need help figuring out how to implement the progress bar into it. Here is an example of the code I am using, so it is easier to understand:

```
Set-Variable $Loading 0
Write-Progress -Activity "Collecting Files For Removal..." -CurrentOperation "Collecting User Files..." -PercentComplete $Loading
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\firea\ -Filter *.D11 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
```

Comment: `Write-Progress` isn't really designed to measure the runtime of a command like `Get-ChildItem`.  You'd more likely use it as a comparison of completion, for example, if you have a collection of files, and you're moving them all, you could utilize `Write-Progress` in a `ForEach` loop to update after each copy or something of that nature.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Well, I have been trying to lay off of loops lately, because they are moderately complex (I just started using Powershell yesterday), and I am trying to stay simple. You do have a point, though... I might try that method with a different project once I get to the more advanced stuff. Do you have any other ideas that could possibly work?

Comment: How would you display a progress bar for a search? The system is not aware of it's upper limit until it is finished. `Get-ChildItem` is a single cmdlet and you can't run anything else in the same thread until it is finished at which point, displaying a progress bar is pointless. If you want a progress bar, the system needs to get the data before hand which means you would have to do a scan first. And you would have to use the much "dreaded" loops you are trying so hard to avoid.

Comment: As suggested by Rohin, you cannot display a progress bar because the system does not know how many total files it has to look at until it is done. In addition to that, PowerShell does one thing at a time without some fairly advanced techniques, so searching the hard drive and displaying/updating a progress bar at the same time is not a trivial request. If you really want to read up on how to do it check out [this link](https://foxdeploy.com/2016/05/17/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars/). If you are a novice, be prepared for your brain to melt a little.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician and @Rohin Sidarth Hmm. Okay. Well, I hope that Microsoft comes out with an addition to the `Get-ChildItem` script that can update a variable every time a file is viewed. But since that probably won't be a thing, are there any Loop programs I can use to do this?

Comment: Just a technicality, but I would like to help you with your terminology to help avoid confusion. `Get-ChildItem` is a cmdlet, not a script. A script is what you get when you compose a series of commands to accomplish one or more tasks. When referring to a loop, it is simply a loop, not a loop program. A program implies something external to PowerShell such as Word, or Internet Explorer.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thank you, but I already know the correct terminology-- I am just really tired from last night so it was hard to think straight enough to word my reply correctly. (Not trying to sound like a KiA lol). Anyway, what I MEANT to say, was I hope they implement a function into the cmdlet that allows a variable to be added and modified according to the User's specifications. Until then, I would like a loop script that would be able to do this instead. (Is that better?)

Answer (score 1):

So, what it sounds like is that you want to show the user a progress bar that displays X% completed, but until you run `Get-ChildItem` you don't know how many total items there are, so you can't really tell how close to done you are. Let me put this another way.

Say you go out and take a hike. You do a quick search online for local trails, find one, and off you go! You know where the trail starts, and you know that there's a corndog stand at the end of it that you're looking forward to sampling. 12 minutes into your hike your girlfriend calls you and asks you to bring her back a corndog too! Sure, no problem, it might be cold by the time it gets to her, but you can do that. Then she asks how long it'll take,and you realize that you have no idea. You're 12 minutes in, but until you get to that corndog stand you have no idea if it's another 3 minutes along, or 35 minutes along, because you don't know how long the trail is.

Ok, same scenario, but this time you see the zip-line that goes over the trail and take that first. Sure, you don't know what all the details of the trail are, but you get a good idea of about how long it is, and a general idea of the trail. This time when your girlfriend calls you can tell her it'll be about 20 minutes, because you're about 12 minutes in, there's about 4 minutes to the stand, and then another 16 minutes back out to where she's at.

Same idea would be applied to your script. In order to give the user even a rough estimate of progress you have to have a rough idea of what you're looking at. Are you searching 1 folder? Well, there's really no good way to get a rough estimate of one folder, but it shouldn't take that long that you'd need a progress bar. Now if you're searching an entire drive you could use the `-directory` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`, find out how many folders there are, and give the user progress based on how many folders you've searched.

Example:

```
#Get directory list, silently continue on errors in case script isn't run as an admin and there are system folders
$folders = Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Recurse -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#Loop through folders, checking each for files
$files = For($i = 0; $i -lt $folders.count; $i++)
{
    #Update progress bar for current folder
    Write-Progress -Activity "Collecting Files For Removal..." -CurrentOperation "Collecting User Files..." -PercentComplete (($i+1) / $folders.count * 100) -Status ("Folder {0} of {1}" -f ($i + 1), $folders.count)
    Get-ChildItem $folders[$i].FullName -Filter *.D11 -ea 4
}
```

This example gets all folders under the C:\Users folder. Then it iterates through those folders checking each one for the desired files. For each folder it updates the progress bar. Now it will be a rough estimate, since not all folders will have the same number of files, so some folders will finish faster than others, but it at least gives the user some idea of the progress being made.

Comment: I think I get the idea-- But keep in mind that my autism makes my mind process things differently, and some of that was a little confusing to me. I would understand a lot better if you supplied a script example that I could use. Thank you for your attempt, though; I appreciate the fact that people are at least trying to help me out here. If you decide to give a script, please try to make the script as simple as possible, because loop scripts are a little weird in Powershell. (I like Python style better than Powershell for this reason)